# Is it possible to read Sphinx binary index?

Tags: binary, sphinx

I have encrypted mysql table via ECB and base64 over it. Searching through big data becomes overheating, so i think about a Sphinx. I can construct index on it and pass all find queries to Sphinx, but is it real to read (steal and read) Sphinx index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sphinx is open source, so the index format is readily available. In fact there is a `indextool` binary, that can show you much of the data from the files. (**but of course if someone can obtain the index files, they could load them into another copy of sphinx and just 'read' them that way**)

... but sphinx indexes are somewhat lossy. They don't store the *raw* text fields that is being indexed. It's converted to an inverted index.

Then there are two types of index....

With a `dict=keywords` index, the keyword list is stored in the index (after transformation by charset_table) 
So while it would be possible to reconstruct the basis of the text of the documents, but not an **exact** reproduction, punctuation and such is lost.

Whereas if you use a `dict=crc` index, then the actual words are NOT stored in the index - only the crc32/fnv64 hashes of the words. So it would be much harder to reconstruct the original text.

... *So while its not really encryption, the hashing process makes it hard to recover data (in the same way as passwords are usually stored hashed)*

(However, attributes are different, they ARE stored as is in the index. They are easily extractable)